# PHP: Determine Text Colour based on value

Tags: php, css

I've stored values in an array and I want to apply conditional formatting to the output when I access them.
I want the text of the values, less than or equal to 10, displayed in red or, greater than 10, displayed in green.

For example, below, I would like the resultant value of 5 to be displayed in red.

I'm a newbie to this but would assume I would need the help of CSS to achieve this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$total_sql=array();
$total_sql[]=5;
$total_sql[]=10;
$total_sql[]=15;
$total_sql[]=20;

print($total_sql[0]);

?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this using pure HTML/CSS, or is this your hangup?

Comment: I don't know how to do this using HTML/CSS.  My job consists of reporting on/querying an Oracle DB using SQL Developer.  I've now been asked to make the reports 'look pretty'.  I'm starting from scratch again but the given answers have solved my initial problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$total_sql=array();
$total_sql[]=5;
$total_sql[]=10;
$total_sql[]=15;
$total_sql[]=20;

print($total_sql[0]);

?>

foreach($total_sql as $item)
{
if($item >10)
{
    echo '<p class="green">'.$item.'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="red">'.$item.'</p>';
}


.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
echo '<div style="color: '.(($score == '5') ? 'red' : 'black').';">'.$score.'</div>';
```

Comparison operator could be:

```
$score == 'x'
        > 'y'
       >= 'z'
etc...
```

I've used an inline style here, but you can use `class=` too.